# Location Updates every 35 seconds and draw a circle on the current location

Tags: java, android, location

Currently I am drawing a `Circle` on my `Current Location` after every 35 seconds of the location changed and 10 meters of distance moved.

So I have implemented this feature under `LocationChanged` as soon as the location gets changed(35 seconds and 10 meters moved), I am drawing a `Circle on the Google Maps on the Current Location`.

**Problem Statement:-**

`My App is running very slow`. Sometimes my app gets hanged?. May be because my code is not that efficient with the way I have wrote below?

Basically, I just need to draw a Circle on my current location after every 35 seconds and 10 meters distance moved.

Is there any problem with my code? Any thoughts like how should I improve this more, to run it smoothly.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

    locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            35000, 
            10, 
            locationListener);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    mapView.setStreetView(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(15);
}

private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                    (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

            findUsersInCurrentRadius(4,location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

            mapController.animateTo(point);
            mapController.setZoom(15);

            // add marker
            MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(this,android.R.drawable.star_on);
            mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
            List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            listOfOverlays.clear();
            listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

            String address = ConvertPointToLocation(point);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            mapView.invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

This is my MapOverlay class in which I am drawing a Circle.

```
class MapOverlay extends Overlay {
    private GeoPoint pointToDraw;
    int[] imageNames=new int[6];

    public MapOverlay(GPSLocationListener gpsLocationListener, int currentUser) {
        imageNames[0]=currentUser;
    }

    public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
        pointToDraw = point;
    }

    public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
        return pointToDraw;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, screenPts);
        //--------------draw circle----------------------
        Point pt = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw,screenPts);
        Paint circlePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        circlePaint.setColor(0x30000000);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        int totalCircle=4;
        int radius=40;
        int centerimagesize=35;

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalCircle; i ++) { 
            canvas.drawCircle(screenPts.x,screenPts.y, i*radius, circlePaint); 
        } 

        canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageNames[0]), (screenPts.x-(centerimagesize/2)),(screenPts.y-(centerimagesize/2)), null);

        super.draw(canvas,mapView,shadow);

        return true;
    }


}
```

**Updated Code:-**

```
private MapView mapView;
private ListView listView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

    locationListener = new GPSLocationListener(mapView);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            35000, 
            0, 
            locationListener);


    mapView.setStreetView(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(15);
}


    private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    MapOverlay mapOverlay;

    public GPSLocationListener(MapView mapView) {
        mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(this,android.R.drawable.star_on);
        List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                    (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                    (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

            mapController.animateTo(point);
            mapController.setZoom(15);

            // **See no need to make a new Object here**
            mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
            mapView.invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}


    class MapOverlay extends Overlay {
    private GeoPoint pointToDraw;
    int[] imageNames=new int[6];
    private Point mScreenPoints;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Paint mCirclePaint;


    public MapOverlay(GPSLocationListener gpsLocationListener, int currentUser) {
        imageNames[0]=currentUser;
        mCirclePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mCirclePaint.setColor(0x30000000);
        mCirclePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageNames[0]);
        mScreenPoints = new Point();
    }

    public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
        pointToDraw = point;
    }

    public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
        return pointToDraw;
    }

    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        mScreenPoints = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, mScreenPoints);

        int totalCircle=4;
        int radius=40;
        int centerimagesize=35;

        for (int i = 1; i <= totalCircle; i ++) { 
            canvas.drawCircle(mScreenPoints.x,mScreenPoints.y, i*radius, mCirclePaint); 
        } 

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, (mScreenPoints.x-(centerimagesize/2)),(mScreenPoints.y-(centerimagesize/2)), null);
        super.draw(canvas,mapView,shadow);

        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: hey your yesterday's problem solved man ?

Comment: Yup it got solved. Thanks for your help. It was because of you, I figured that out. Any thoughts on this question? How to make it more efficient?

Comment: ok good, 35 seconds is very short period, you should atleast have 1 min's interval, also you have requested 10 meter's accuracy, so that requires more time to get exact position, so you should increase your time interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a few things to remember when drawing:

1. Do not block the Main UI Thread
2. Remember Recycle objects.
3. Remember Recycle objects.
4. And always Remember to Recycle Objects.

**Possible UI Thread Blockage**

This code looks like it is calling a potentially expensive action on the callback of `onLocationChanged()` which is really dangerous to do because you could end up in an ANR. This should probably be done on a background AsyncTask and then the toast shown on the result of it.

```
String address = ConvertPointToLocation(point);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Better Management of Resources on Maps**

Instead of adding a new overlay each time, make sure to recycle the instance and just reset it's position.

```
private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    MapOverlay mOverlay;

    public GPSLocationListener() {

    }

   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

        findUsersInCurrentRadius(4,location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

        mapController.animateTo(point);
        mapController.setZoom(15);

        if (mOverlay == null) {
            // Add this marker to the list of overlays always.
            // This stuff never changes so there is no need to do this logic
            // Every 30 secs. Loading images is **Expensive**
            mOverlay = mMapOverlay = new MapOverlay(this,android.R.drawable.star_on);
            List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
            listOfOverlays.add(mMapOverlay);
        }
        // **See, no need to make a new Object here**
        mOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);

        // This can probably be done at another time.
        // String address = ConvertPointToLocation(point);
        // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mapView.invalidate();
    }
```

This code can reuse this marker and just update it's position. You should only create one if it is not in the list.

**Better Drawing**

Ok next remember don't create objects in the onDraw() method if you don't have to. 
Once the marker knows where to draw to, you should have everything cached so that you can just focus on drawing. For Example:

```
public class MapOverlay {

    private GeoPoint pointToDraw;
    int[] imageNames=new int[6];
    // This is the cached Point on the screen that will get refilled on every draw
    private Point mScreenPoints;
    // This is the cached decoded bitmap that will be drawn each time
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    // Cached Paint
    private Paint mCirclePaint;

    public MapOverlay(GPSLocationListener gpsLocationListener, int currentUser) {
      imageNames[0]=currentUser;
      // This only needs to be made here, once. It never needs to change.
      mCirclePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      mCirclePaint.setColor(0x30000000);
      mCirclePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
      // We only need to load this image once and then just keep drawing it when dirtyed.
      mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),imageNames[0]);
      // This Point object will be changed every call to toPixels(), but the instance can be recycled
      mScreenPoints = new Point();
    }

    public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
      pointToDraw = point;
    }

    public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
      return pointToDraw;
    }

    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
      super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
      // In the case where nothing has been set yet, don't do any drawing
      if (pointToDraw == null) {
         return true;
      }
      //--------------draw circle----------------------
      mScreenPoints = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, mScreenPoints);

      int totalCircle=4;
      int radius=40;
      int centerimagesize=35;

      for (int i = 1; i <= totalCircle; i ++) { 
          canvas.drawCircle(screenPts.x,screenPts.y, i*radius, mCirclePaint); 
      } 

      canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, (screenPts.x-(centerimagesize/2)),(screenPts.y-(centerimagesize/2)), null);
      super.draw(canvas,mapView,shadow);

      return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Greg for the suggestion. After making changes in my code as suggested by you, I started getting `Null Pointer Exception` in my code. And it is happening at this line `Point pt = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, mScreenPts);` why?

Comment: Well in my code right now there is a compilation error. Sorry not a machine that can compile code. But the variable is mScreenPoints. I will update this now.

Comment: And what about the Null Pointer Exception that I am facing. Any thoughts?

Comment: The mapView is not null and the pointToDraw instance is not null, and the code should initialize the mScreenPoints to a Point instance so there should be no null pointer. If there is, I suspect something is not being initialized in your code.

Comment: I have updated my full code in the question with all your changes as mentioned above. Can you let me know what wrong I am doing?

Comment: Okay. I think, I found the problem. Ppreviously I used to get the GoogleMap on the top half of the Android Screen and it waits for me to pass the location coordinates from the DDMS perspective. But now after I have made the changes, it directly thinks that location coordinates has been passed and I didn't passed any coordinates from the DDMS. So that is the reason it is throwing NPE. How should I fix this?

Comment: Check for null and then don't draw?

Comment: I can do that, but why it is going directly, that's my question is. Default behavior should be Google Map should get loaded firstly. And it should wait to get the location updates right? I am testing this on the emulator firstly.

Comment: These things get tricky fast with the location manager. So one thing it may be is that, you updated your code to have a minDistance from 10m to 0m. That could mean, depending on the device, send whenever another sensor, like an accelerometer, sees any movement and there is still no location in the data buffer from the GPS sensor, you may end up with null (Weird but I guess possible). You may want to start the overlay after the first location has been set. Up until recently the Location Apis were a little fuzzy. Jellybean I believe solves a lot of these because of compatibility restrictions.

Comment: Hey Greg, I have commented out this line `mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);` but still it throws NPE at the same line `mScreenPoints = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, mScreenPoints);` Why? It looks like my MapOverlay class is getting called automatically.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16750/discussion-between-greg-and-techgeeky)

Comment: Updated the code to check for the null. Added the map overlay too soon. whoops :)

Comment: Thanks Greg for all your help. Appreciated your help in making me understand few things. :)