# Continuously updating Google Maps with user location

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, web

I am super new to web development and building a web app that has a google map and would like to continuously update the map with the user location. I am able to read values from my db properly and can display it on the map, but only one time. I could not find anywhere how to continuously update the position (hopefully without reloading the page also). Can someone help with some direction on how to approach this? Here some of my code for reference:

```
<?php include_once('location.php') ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My GeoLocation</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>


    <script>

var map;
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $current_lat ?>, <?php echo $current_long ?>);

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'TEST'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>


//READ FROM CLIENT (POST)
$content = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post_data = json_decode($content , true);
$lat = $post_data['lat'];
$long = $post_data['long'];
$speed = $post_data['speed'];
$hacc = $post_data['hacc'];
$vacc = $post_data['vacc'];
$timestamp = $post_data['timestampe'];


//CONNECT TO MYSQL
$con1 = mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxxxxx", "bbbbbb", "yyyyyy");
if ($con1->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('yyyyyy');
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

if (!empty($lat)) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO LocationInfo (latitude, longitude, speed, hor_acc, ver_acc, d) 
                VALUES ('$lat', '$long', '$speed', '$hacc', '$vacc', '$timestamp');";
  mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error updating database: ' . mysql_error());
 }

$read_query = "SELECT * FROM LocationInfo;";
$results = mysql_query($read_query) or die ('Error reading from database: ' . mysql_error());
$column = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
    $column[] = $row;
}

$current_lat = $column[sizeof($column) - 1]['latitude'];
$current_long = $column[sizeof($column) - 1]['longitude'];

?>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451722/location-updates-every-35-seconds-and-draw-a-circle-on-the-current-location

Comment: can u show me the code of  this <?php include_once('location.php') ?>  i mean Location.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Maps JavaScript reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

You can update the marker with `marker.setPosition( new LatLng(...) )`, or in other words just assigning a new position. It seems to me you're putting your position in an input field, than submitting, reading the field and setting the marker and saving the position in a database. If you want to update the position of the marker, you can use an input field again, read the field value with JavaScript, and update the marker's position (with marker.setPosition()). If you want to pass this to your DB again, you can additionally pass the data to your script using AJAX. It depends on what you're doing and want you want to do.

**edited after comment**

You can setup a JavaScript function that will make an AJAX request to your PHP script and update the position once it gets the data. And then call the script every x number of seconds. use `setTimeout` to create a delay and then make the function call itself with another timeout once it gets the data. Save yourself the trouble and use a library to handle your AJAX calls - jQuery gives you indirectly a lot of support because a lot of people use it. You also need to make sure your PHP script doesn't give you anything back except the position information, not the whole html file as you have now. So simplified something like this: you have a PHP file that sends you the lat/lng pair as JSON, and this script gets called from the browser around every 10 seconds. There are ofcourse little things that might pop out ... and please note, I don't do PHP.

**get_position.php**

```
...
$latLng = array('lat' => $lat, 'lng' => $lng);
echo json_encode($latLng);
```

**JS, using jQuery.ajax**

```
var marker = ....
var delay = 10000; // 10 second delay

function updatePosition() {
    $.ajax({
        url: path/to/get_position.php,
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function callDone(data) {
        // update marker position
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng( data.lat, data.lng );
        marker.setPosition( latLng );
        // call the function again
        setTimeout( updatePosition, delay );
    });
}
// call the function initally
setTimeout( updatePosition, delay );
```

Comment: The PHP is where I get the coordinates from (I save to the DB from an iphone client). Looks like the coordinates are not refreshed since the php is not called again. How can I call the php periodically?